# Sharepoint API/CSOM: How to change file content without changing version history?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a sharepoint site with a document list with files behind one fileitem and the version history for this list is enabled. Now I'm trying to update the file content of a file without creating a new version, but I can't find a way to do so.

The possiblities I have is with Sharepoint REST API or Sharepoint CSOM (C# Object Model).

I know how to update a file content with a version change, but I can't find a way to do so without. And most forum entries just mention the change of a fileitem without a change of the version history - but that's not what I'm searching for.